# jEditable: not showing cell content while editing text

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables, jeditable, jquery-datatables-editor

I am using jEditable plugin on my table. It works fine but while editing any cell, its content gets disappeared (it just shows the plain input text box with no value) and once I am done with editing and hit enter , it shows complete text (existing text+ edited text). Here is code snippet -

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extensions/TableTools/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extensions/TableTools/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link href="media/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="extensions/Plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/resultTable.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jeditable.js"></script>



<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>

<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dbResultsTable').DataTable( {
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers" ,
        "paging":   true,
        "ordering" : true,
        "scrollY":false,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "info":     true ,
        "scrollX": "100%" ,
        "sScrollXInner": "110%",
        "lengthMenu": [[5,10, 25, 50, -1], [5,10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        columnDefs: [
       { "type": "html-string", "targets": 1 },
       { "type": "html-string", "targets": 2 },
       { "type": "html-string", "targets": 3 },
       { "type": "html-string", "targets": 4 },
       { "type": "html-string", "targets": 5 }

        ],
        "dom": '<"top"iflp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"iflp<"clear">>' 
        }
      );

        });


</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { /* Init DataTables */
    var oTable = $('#dbResultsTable').dataTable();

    var theCallback = function(v, s) {
        return v;
    };
    $(oTable).find('td').editable(theCallback, {

        "callback": function(sValue, y) {
            oTable.fnUpdate(sValue);
        },
    });
});
</script>
<style>
 table { table-layout: auto; }
 table {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>
<style type="text/css"> 
         td{ 
         text-align:center; 
         } 
      </style> 
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out `<TD></TD>` tags were having newline characher and lot of space character .Data was already there but not visible because of unwanted extra character. Hope it helps someone.